# My app is taking database files that don't exist

Tags: sqlite

something apparently without any reason is happening.

My app was using a SQLite database that was in the assets folder and copied in the app databases folder.

Then to make some tests i removed the file from the assets folder in Android Studio, i cleared all the app data on the phone, uninstalled the app and then i run my project in debug

I have then a procedure that checks if there is already a database file in the app folder and I can't explain how but it seems the database is still there and i can read records from it!!

How could it be possible?
Where is the app taking this database?

**EDIT**

Here is the code i use to check if the database exists:

```
private boolean checkDataBase() {
        SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

        try {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        }catch(SQLiteException e){
        }

        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
        }

        return checkDB != null ? true : false;
    }
```

where myPath is: /data/user/0/packagename/databases/mydb.db

please note that the "mydb.db" file does not exist in my Android Studio project, but when I load it I can also query it and get real results

Comment: Post your code for checking database

Comment: I have the feeling that the database comes somehow from a backup on the cloud. I tried to disable data connections before launching the app and the function above says the database does not exist! do you confirm?